# Rectangle drawing issue in Pygame Python

Tags: python, pygame

So I'm kinda new at Pygame, and just trying to create easy projects to learn.

I've created a basic rectangle first as player, and I want to implement a system where user clicks to somewhere in screen and game spawns a rectangle at that point. Here's my code:

```
import pygame
import sys
from pygame import *
from pygame.mouse import get_pos
pygame.init()

SCREEN_WIDTH = 800
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH,SCREEN_HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Touch To Create Blocks!")

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.surf = pygame.Surface((50,50))
        self.surf.fill((220,120,37))
        self.rect = self.surf.get_rect()

    def update(self,pressed_keys):
        if pressed_keys[pygame.K_UP]:
            self.rect.move_ip(0,-5)
        elif pressed_keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            self.rect.move_ip(0,5)
        elif pressed_keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.rect.move_ip(-5,0)
        elif pressed_keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.rect.move_ip(5,0)

        if self.rect.left < 0:
            self.rect.left = 0
        elif self.rect.right > SCREEN_WIDTH:
            self.rect.right = SCREEN_WIDTH
        elif self.rect.top <= 0:
            self.rect.top = 0
        elif self.rect.top >= SCREEN_HEIGHT - 50:
            self.rect.bottom = SCREEN_HEIGHT

player = Player()

run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            run = False
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                run = False
                sys.exit()
        elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            mouse_x, mouse_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            rectangle = pygame.Rect(mouse_x, mouse_y, 40, 40)
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,255,255) , rectangle)
            pygame.display.update()
            
    screen.fill((0,0,0))
    pressed_keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    player.update(pressed_keys)
    screen.blit(player.surf,player.rect)
    pygame.display.update()
```

With that code, when I click, a block spawns and disappears immediately. How do I fix this? Thanks for your help.

(Sorry for my bad English)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when the user clicks you draw the rectangle
(`pygame.draw.rect`), update the display (`pygame.display.update`) and
then, after the for loop, you empty the display
(`screen.fill((0,0,0))`).  This explains why the rectangle disappears
immediately.

Instead of calling `pygame.draw.rect` each time the user clicks on the
screen, you can instead memorise the rectangle and save it into a
list.  Then you have can draw all rectangles you memorised at each
iteration of your main loop.

Here is an implementation of this solution (I have added comments in
the code):

```py
import pygame
import sys
from pygame import *
from pygame.mouse import get_pos
pygame.init()

SCREEN_WIDTH = 800
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH,SCREEN_HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Touch To Create Blocks!")

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.surf = pygame.Surface((50,50))
        self.surf.fill((220,120,37))
        self.rect = self.surf.get_rect()

    def update(self,pressed_keys):
        if pressed_keys[pygame.K_UP]:
            self.rect.move_ip(0,-5)
        elif pressed_keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            self.rect.move_ip(0,5)
        elif pressed_keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.rect.move_ip(-5,0)
        elif pressed_keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.rect.move_ip(5,0)

        if self.rect.left < 0:
            self.rect.left = 0
        elif self.rect.right > SCREEN_WIDTH:
            self.rect.right = SCREEN_WIDTH
        elif self.rect.top <= 0:
            self.rect.top = 0
        elif self.rect.top >= SCREEN_HEIGHT - 50:
            self.rect.bottom = SCREEN_HEIGHT

player = Player()

run = True
rectangles = list()  # list of the rectangles we have to draw
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            run = False
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                run = False
                sys.exit()
        elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            # add a new rectangle to our list of rectangles
            mouse_x, mouse_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            rectangles.append(pygame.Rect(mouse_x, mouse_y, 40, 40))
            
    screen.fill((0,0,0))
    pressed_keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    player.update(pressed_keys)
    screen.blit(player.surf,player.rect)

    #  draw all the rectangles we memorised
    for rectangle in rectangles:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,255,255) , rectangle)
    pygame.display.update()
```